# What are the odds in favor of the draw yielding maximum amount given the following conditions?

Tags: probability

> A bag contains $4$ $5$Rs coins,$3$ $2$Rs coins and $3$ $1$Rs coins.If $6$ coins are drawn from the bag at random,What are the odds in favor of the draw yielding maximum amount?

My Approach:

To yield maximum amount,out of 10 coins i can take only $4$ $5$Rs coins and $2$ $2$Rs coins.

Possible Outcomes can be $4$ $5$Rs coins and $2$ $2$Rs coins,$3$ $2$Rs coins and $3$ $1$Rs coins,$4$ $5$Rs coins and $1$ $2$Rs coins and $1$ $1$Rs coins or $4$ $5$Rs coins and $1$ $3$Rs coins and $1$ $2$Rs coins.

P=1/4

But i am getting wrong Ans.Can Anyone give me Hint why?

Comment: Firstly there are more possible outcomes. Secondly not all outcomes do not have equal probabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

There are $\binom{10}{6}$ ways to draw $6$ coins from the bag with $10$ coins.

How many ways are there to do that under the restriction that $4$ of the drawn coins are 5Rs coins and $2$ of the drawn coins are 2Rs coins?

Comment: There are no 4 Rs coins. You must have meant: "2of the 2Rs coins."

Comment: @zoli Thank you. Repaired.